# How to use select for last month and specific day

Tags: jquery, sql, date, select, time

I need to select last months but between specific hours. If i choose a specific day of a month - for ex. 28.03.2021 - it works fine, but when i need to combine last month and specific hours, it is problem.

I have this

```
AND day >= to_date(to_char(add_months(trunc(sysdate,'mm'),-1)))
AND day between '09:00:00 HH24:MI:SS' AND '09:30:00 HH24:MI:SS'
```

WHAT WORKS WITH SPECIFIC DAY

```
AND day >= to_date ('21.12.2020 09:00:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
AND day <= to_date ('21.12.2020 09:30:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
```

I need get back all selected values from 01.02.2021 - 28.02.2021(or march, april...) but just with written time between 09:00 - 09:30
the column "day" have written date and time together like this - 01.03.2021 8:05:03

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably, you are using Oracle.  For a specific day, use a `timestamp` constant:

```
day >= timestamp '2020-12-21 09:00:00' and
day <= timestamp '2020-12-21 09:30:00'
```

If you want all days last month, then between the times of 9:00 and 9:30:

```
day >= add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'MON'), -1) and
day >= trunc(sysdate, 'MON') and
to_char(day, 'HH24:MI:SS') between '09:00:00' and '09:30:00'
```